# Twitter, tweepy, search_30_day - doesn't produce any results comparing to norma look

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Could somebody point me what i am doing wrong in here?
When using normal look without premium feature i got results

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key': consumer_key, 'consumer_secret': consumer_secret,
              'access_token_key': access_token, 'access_token_secret': access_token_secret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)
cricTweet = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='', geocode='60.00,10.00,40km').items(10)

how_many_tweets = 0
for tweet in cricTweet:
    how_many_tweets += 1
print(how_many_tweets)

premiumTweet = api.search_30_day(environment_name='dev', query='point_radius:[60.00 10.00 40km]',
                             fromDate=202012300000, maxResults=100)

how_many_tweets = 0
for tweet in premiumTweet:
    how_many_tweets += 1

print(how_many_tweets)
```

but when trying to do the same with premium search_30_day i got no results back and my question is what i am doing wrong